# animar función en python

Tags: python, funciones, matplotlib, animación

tengo este código que me grafica la siguiente función matemática y me gustaría realizar una pequeña animación de ella.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import shift
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.animation as animation

b = 23.9/1000 #  radio cátodo
a = 20*10**(-12) #  Radio del ánodo 
V_0 = 2000 #  voltaje 

r = np.arange(0, b,b/40) #  Radio desde cero hasta b
E = V_0/(r*np.log(b/a))  #  Campo eléctrico en función de r
plt.plot(r,E, 'red')
plt.xlim(0,0.025)
plt.title('Campo eléctrico en función de la discancia radial')
plt.xlabel('Distancia radial [m]')
plt.ylabel('Campo eléctrico [V/m]')
plt.show
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estaba intentando hacer lo siguiente pero no me funcionó. creo que el principal problema está en la parte de frames = np.arange()

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots()
r_datos, E_datos = [], []

graficar, = plt.plot([ ], [ ])

def lim():
  axes.set_xlim(0,b)
  axes.set_ylim(0,160000)
  return graficar,

def funcion(r):
  r_datos.append(r)
  E_datos.append( V_0/(r*np.log(b/a)) )
  graficar.set_data(r_datos, E_datos)
  return graficar,

FuncAnimation(fig,funcion, frames=np.arange(0, b,b/40), init_func=lim, blit=True)
plt.show
```

Comment: tienes algun error por consola?

Comment: No, no es ningún error por consola. El código simplemente no muestra nada

Comment: no deberias unsar `np.linspace()`

Answer (score 0):

caí acá porque estaba buscando cómo animar funciones. En otro enlace vi un ejemplo básico (creo que de matplotlib.org), en fin me puse a ver cómo graficar unas figuras en polares y anduvo bien usando esa referencia. Así que me puse a probar lo tuyo, además de que trabajo en física (educación), puede ser que esto sirva, al menos anduvo:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

b = 23.9/1000 #  radio cátodo
a = 20*10**(-12) #  Radio del ánodo 
V_0 = 2000 #  voltaje 

r = np.arange(0, b,b/40) #  Radio desde cero hasta b
E = V_0/(r*np.log(b/a))  #  Campo eléctrico en función de r
line, = plt.plot(r,E, 'red')
#plt.xlim(0,0.025)
plt.title('Campo eléctrico en función de la distancia radial')
plt.xlabel('Distancia radial [m]')
plt.ylabel('Campo eléctrico [V/m]')

def animate(i):
    line.set_ydata(V_0/((r+i/10.0)*np.log(b/a)))
    return line,


def init():
    line.set_ydata(np.ma.array(r, mask=True))
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = r, init_func = init,
                              interval = 100, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

fijate que comenté la línea plt.xlim porque dibujaba un sombreado. A mayor intervalo más lenta la animación.

Ahora me resta entender bien qué hace la función `animate` cuando se le suma `i`, aunque parece que se trata de incrementar `r`. Probé con otras funciones y parece que la lógica es la misma.

Espero te sirva como a mí.

Saludos!

Darío